# In macOS AppleScript, how do I check if a property exists?

Tags: macos, applescript

In AppleScript I access an object in an application, e.g.:

```applescript
tell application id "DNtp"
  repeat with g in (children of root of (think window 1))
       set theAnnotation to annotation of g
  end
end tell
```

I know that depending on the child accessed, `g` sometimes has no `annotation` property.

**N.B.** This is *not the same* as having a `missing value` or something like that.

When running the code,  AppleScript simply complains that the variable `theAnnotation` is not defined.

Other than trapping the error with a `try ... on error` statement, how do I check if `g` has the property `annotation`?

Comment: AFAIK, vanilla AppleScript doesn't provide a builtin feature analogous to e.g. JavaScript's [`hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) method.

Comment: @RobC Yes, I was indeed considering resorting to JXA to solve this. Thanks!

Comment: The AS analogy is `exists`. See my answer.

Comment: `hasOwnProperty` is unlikely to help: Apple event property specifiers are unrelated to JavaScript properties. Two possibilities: 1. The app defines two window “subclasses”, one with an `annotation` property and one without; if so, change your reference to specify the former only. 2. The app is buggy: instead of returning `missing value` to indicate “no value” it returns a null descriptor or nothing at all, which AS treats as literally no value. If so, file a bug report on it and use CRGreen’s list trick as a workaround: `repeat with g in (get annotation of children…)`

Comment: Just to clarify, my first comment mentioned JavaScript's `hasOwnProperty` method as an exemplar - it was not meant to imply that JXA was necessarily the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use DEVON-related software, but in ordinary<sup>1</sup> situations when dealing with AppleScript records, [`CRGreen`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2092796/crgreen)'s suggestions won't apply: `exists` is not a command that properties understand, especially non-existent properties; and referencing a property that does not exist will throw an error.

I'm glad you're looking for an alternative to `try...end try`.  I've seen your previous code samples that are drowning in them, and they are expensive operations when an error is caught, so not ideal for what you're attempting.  `try` really has no place in AppleScript at all.

Rather than testing for the existence of a property within a `record`, the way to approach this in a general context is to create a `record` object that contains all the property values that would ever be needed, and to assign default values to each of them.

In AppleScript, a `record` is observed to follow the following behaviour:

- A single `record` object can only contain one property with a given identifier.  Should you attempt to insert two properties both of which are identified the same, the compiler will keep the first property and its associated value, and scrub the rest:

  ```
  {a:1, b:2, a:3} # will resolve on compilation immediately to {a:1, b:2}
  ```
- Two `record` objects can contain properties with shared identifiers, like so:

  ```
  set L to {a:1, b:2, c:3}
  set R to {d:missing value, c:L}
  ```

  Similarly to `list` objects, two `record` objects can be merged into a single `record`, and the properties will be amalgamated: properties with identifiers unique to each `record` will simply be inserted without any change into the resulting data structure.  Where an identifier occurs in both `record` objects before the merge, again, precedence is given in a left-to-right reading order, so the properties in the prefixed `record` (on the left) will prevail and the suffixed `record` (on the right) will have its non-unique property identifiers (and their values) scrubbed:

  ```
  L & R --> {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:missing value}
  R & L --> {d:missing value, c:{a:1, b:2, c:3}, a:1, b:2}
  ```

---

Your code snippet contains this:

```
repeat with g in (children of root of (think window 1))
     set theAnnotation to annotation of g
end
```

Therefore, `g` is an item contained within `children` (a `list` object), and the type class of `g` is a `record`.  Depending on which item of `children` is being examined, I'm assuming that some of those items are records that **do** contain a property identified by `annotation`, and some of those items are records that **do not** contain such a property.

However, consider the following `record` that results from this merge:

```
g & {annotation:missing value}
```

Here are the two possible scenarios:

- `g` is a `record` that already contains a property identified as `annotation`, e.g.:

  ```
  set g to {cannotation:"doe", bannotation:"ray", annotation:me}
  g & {annotation:missing value} --> {cannotation:"doe", bannotation:"ray", annotation:«script»}

  set theAnnotation to annotation of (g & {annotation:missing value})
       --> «script» (i.e. me)
  ```

  **OR:**
- `g` is a `record` that in which the property identifier `annotation` does not exist, e.g.:

  ```
  set g to {doe:"a deer", ray:"a drop of golden sun"}
  g & {annotation:missing value} --> {doe:"a deer", ray:"a drop of golden sun", annotation:missing value}

  set theAnnotation to annotation of (g & {annotation:missing value})
      --> missing value
  ```

Therefore, for every place in your scripts where `try...end try` has been used to catch non-occurrences of properties inside a `record` data structure, simply delete the `try` blocks, and wherever you are assign values read from speculative property values, artificially insert default values you can then test for and will know whether or not the value came from your DEVONthink source or from your brain:

```
tell application id "DNtp"
  repeat with g in (children of root of (think window 1))
       set theAnnotation to annotation of (g & {annotation:false})
       if theAnnotation ≠ false then exit repeat
  end
end tell
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>*This isn't in any way meant to suggest his solution isn't viable.  If DEVON returns collections that are not de-referenced--and it very well may do--these can be operated upon as a whole, without looping through individual items, and he, of course, uses DEVON.  But the situation I hopefully address above is one that arises much more commonly, and will also work here*.</sub>

Comment: @CJK, I wasn't aware of the "merge" property of records in Applescript. This is a very elegant solution.  Regarding your remark about @CRGreen's suggestion to use `exists`, I initially agreed with you. But, as I've comment below @CRGreen's answer, a bit of experimentation confirms that it works for DEVONThink objects.  According to "Applescript, the definitive guide, 2nd" p344, the exists command is to be implemented by the application. And in case of DEVONThink, this is the case, just check the dictionary by searching for `exists`.

Comment: @CJK So, your solution is generally applicable and that was the context of my question and therefore I've to vote for your solution.

Answer (score 4):

If you do

```
tell application id "DNtp"
    annotation of children of root of (think window 1)
end tell
```

You'll get a list containing annotations and if those are missing, `missing value`s, like:

```
--{missing value, missing value, missing value, «class DTcn» id 49 of «class DTkb» id 1, missing value}
```

The problem you describe in DEVONthink (of AS ignoring a declared variable during compile time) is a problem I've seen in other apps, too (but it's fairly rare).

If you want to check for the existence of a property, what usually works (and I've tested this with DEVONthink3) is to use `exists`, like:

```
if (exists annotation of g) then
```

Which will return true or false as you would expect. Not sure how you'd use that in the way you first posted, but I don't really know all the steps you're taking, so ....

I hope this helps

Comment: your solution is the one closest to my own style of programming.  Nice thank you.  I should have experimented with `exists`, but from the Apple dev docs I got the impression it wouldn't work.

Comment: I wish I had asked the question specificly for DEVONthink, as your solution is indeed most relevant to the underlying motivation for posting this question on SE. Nevertheless, I gave your solution a vote.  See also my comment above regarding the nature of `exists`.
I use your solution in my Applescript.

Comment: Are you saying my answer is the solution?

Comment: Well, I've tried to explain that, but the explanation is scattered over the comments. To summarise: The posted question asked for a _general_ solution applicable to every situation. CJK solved that one.  You recognized from the application id that it was about DEVONthink and gave me a relevant and working solution for that specific application in my particular circumstances from which I distilled the posted question.
Please believe me that I found it difficult to decide which answer to award with the "solved" checkmark as SE only allows me to chose 1. But I did upvote yours.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well-explained. Glad I could contribute.